# How to accurately track mouse movements in python, tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So i am trying to make a simple Drawpad using python and tkinter, and i have pretty much got it working, except there is massive gaps in between the individual dots.

[Heres an example](https://gyazo.com/7d023bc32cb9050beb99eac5224ba60a)

I was wondering if there is a more accurate mouse tracking method? Heres my code for making the dots.

```
def draw(event):
    global DotSize
    arr = []
    arr.append([event.x, event.y])
    for i in arr:
        yes=i[0]
        no=i[1]
        Canvas.create_oval(yes,no,yes,no, fill="black", width=DotSize)

//Theres a load more code in here but i dont think its relevant.

Canvas.bind("<B1 Motion>",draw)
```

Thanks!

Comment: draw line from previous position to current position

Comment: some form of interpolation is required

Comment: How do i draw a line from the previous point to the new point?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are redrawing every pixel every time. First you draw one oval. Then you draw two. then you draw three, and so on. You only need to draw the last item in the array.

As for the accuracy -- what you are doing is the most accurate way to track mouse movement in tkinter. There's nothing more efficient than binding to `<B1-Motion>`.